# search display template filter query

Tags: search-results, managed-property

I've created a search query to get all SharePoint Sites where I have access to. 
This was made with the results webpart and a search query. When I'm trying to search in this list the results won't be reduced. With managed properties in the search box for example **title:Testsite** everything works fine.
Maybe someone has an idea how to fix it.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What is your query? Are you searching for Sites or items in a list of sites? Which version of SharePoint?

Comment: Hi.
The query is **{searchboxquery} contentclass=STS_Web contentclass=STS_Site EGGPBSiteType=Project -Path:https://sp.egger.com/templates EGGPBProjectStatus<>Closed**
The EGGPBSiteType and EGGPBProject Status are custom managed properties. With this Query I'm getting all our active project sites. If somebody is searching for a bracket of a name e.g. test the search results without doing with a managed property e.g. "Title:test" the search results webpart also displays all results like before. In some cases I saw that the results were reduced by 1 item.

Comment: you are missing * in your query, and use {searchTerm}* instead of {searchboxquery}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
{searchTerm}* (contentclass=STS_Web contentclass:STS_Site EGGPBSiteType=Project -Path:"http://sp.egger.com/templates" EGGPBProjectStatus<>Closed)
```

Make sure you have quotes around the URL and managed properties are correct.
The first answer has a good point that you don't need the contentclass because your custom properties are very specific.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I changed the query and removed STS_Site, STS_Web and Path and everything worked. The main problem is that I implemented a sorting at the search results webpart without the "Relevance" sorting. Without this the search results won't be changed if somebody is searching a site. The main request was to filter the search results which were provided by the above mentioned query but this is only possible with refinements (cause I haven't found any other solution).

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try removing the Site Collection from your query. More than likely you can also remove the Web too since you are using the very specific `EGGPBSiteType=Project`.